# How to use a property from a constructor inside an instance method in Kotin?

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, scope, instance-variables

This is my code.

```
class Repository(context: Context) {

    // Can access 'context' from here
    val mSharedPrefsProperties = context
        .getSharedPreferences(context.packageName.plus(".properties"), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    // Can't access 'context' in this function (unresolved reference: context)
    private fun getApiKey(): String {
        val apiKeys = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.api_keys)
        val random = Random().nextInt(apiKeys.size)
        return apiKeys[random]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access the properties from the constructor inside functions or do I need to make them a instance/local variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple constructor parameters don't become properties of your class. That only happens by explitly making them `var` or `val`. You can, nevertheless, access those simple params in anything related to initialization, for example:

```
class ConstWithArg(param1: String) {
    init {
        println(param1)
    }

    val field1 = param1.length
    var field2 = param1.length

}
```

If you need to access the parameter after construction, it should become a property by making it a `val`. If you don't want anyone else to access this field outside your class, mark it as private:

```
class ConstWithArg(private val param1: String) {

    fun useProp(){
        println(param1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just put `var` (or `val`) on the arguments

```
class Repository(var context: Context) {

    // Can access 'context' from here
    val mSharedPrefsProperties = context
        .getSharedPreferences(context.packageName.plus(".properties"), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    // Can't access 'context' in this function (unresolved reference: context)
    private fun getApiKey(): String {
        val apiKeys = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.api_keys)
        val random = Random().nextInt(apiKeys.size)
        return apiKeys[random]
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha it was so simple! Thanks! Btw what is the difference between putting var/val on the constructor property and leaving it blank?

Comment: yes =) here the doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: @appersiano I agree with you, actually I think that the context should be immutable within the Repository class, so I would opt for val